# Are XML Comments Necessary Documentation?

Tags: .net, programming-practices, development-process, documentation, comments

I used to be a fan of requiring XML comments for documentation. I've since changed my mind for two main reasons:

> 1. Like good code, methods should be self-explanatory.
> 2. In practice, most XML comments are useless noise that provide no additional value.

Many times we simply use GhostDoc to generate generic comments, and this is what I mean by useless noise:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the unit of measure.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The unit of measure.
    /// </value>
    public string UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
```

To me, that's obvious. Having said that, if there were special instructions to include, then we should absolutely use XML comments.

I like this excerpt from this [article](http://elegantcode.com/2010/04/18/eliminating-comments-the-road-to-clarity/):

> Sometimes, you will need to write comments. But, it should be the exception not the rule. Comments should only be used when they are expressing something that cannot be expressed in code. If you want to write elegant code, strive to eliminate comments and instead write self-documenting code.

**Am I wrong to think we should only be using XML comments when the code isn't enough to explain itself on its own?**

I believe this is a good example where XML comments make pretty code look ugly. It takes a class like this...

```
public class RawMaterialLabel : EntityBase
{
    public long     Id                      { get; set; }
    public string   ManufacturerId          { get; set; }
    public string   PartNumber              { get; set; }
    public string   Quantity                { get; set; }
    public string   UnitOfMeasure           { get; set; }
    public string   LotNumber               { get; set; }
    public string   SublotNumber            { get; set; }
    public int      LabelSerialNumber       { get; set; }
    public string   PurchaseOrderNumber     { get; set; }
    public string   PurchaseOrderLineNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime ManufacturingDate       { get; set; }
    public string   LastModifiedUser        { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModifiedTime        { get; set; }
    public Binary   VersionNumber           { get; set; }

    public ICollection<LotEquipmentScan> LotEquipmentScans { get; private set; }
}
```

... And turns it into this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Container for properties of a raw material label
/// </summary>
public class RawMaterialLabel : EntityBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the id.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The id.
    /// </value>
    public long Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the manufacturer id.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The manufacturer id.
    /// </value>
    public string ManufacturerId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the part number.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The part number.
    /// </value>
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the quantity.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The quantity.
    /// </value>
    public string Quantity { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the unit of measure.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The unit of measure.
    /// </value>
    public string UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the lot number.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The lot number.
    /// </value>
    public string LotNumber { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the sublot number.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The sublot number.
    /// </value>
    public string SublotNumber { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the label serial number.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The label serial number.
    /// </value>
    public int LabelSerialNumber { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the purchase order number.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The purchase order number.
    /// </value>
    public string PurchaseOrderNumber { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the purchase order line number.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The purchase order line number.
    /// </value>
    public string PurchaseOrderLineNumber { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the manufacturing date.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The manufacturing date.
    /// </value>
    public DateTime ManufacturingDate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the last modified user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The last modified user.
    /// </value>
    public string LastModifiedUser { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the last modified time.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The last modified time.
    /// </value>
    public DateTime LastModifiedTime { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the version number.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The version number.
    /// </value>
    public Binary VersionNumber { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the lot equipment scans.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The lot equipment scans.
    /// </value>
    public ICollection<LotEquipmentScan> LotEquipmentScans { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: I would argue XML is a terrible choice for this purpose. It's way too verbose and general for the use at hand. Check out [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) and [sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) for a markup language that embeds into comments without making them unreadable.

Comment: @Lattyware: VisualStudio supports this style by default, no extra plugins or tools are necessary. Comments generated this way are immediately visible in pop-up tooltips.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner I would say that getting a plugin is worth it to make your code far more readable. Built-in support for reST with tooltips like that is in PyCharm, so I'm sure plugins exist for other languages in other IDEs. Obviously if you have a project where everything is documented in this way, I'm not suggesting you start splitting the way it's done, but for new projects, I just think it's so horrible to read and maintain.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If your comments only look like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the sublot number.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
/// The sublot number.
/// </value>
```

Then yes, they are not all that useful. If they read something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the sublot number.
/// Note that the sublot number is only used by the legacy inventory system.
/// Latest version of the online inventory system does not use this, so you can leave it null. 
/// Some vendors require it but if you don't set it they'll send a request for it specifically.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
/// The sublot number.
/// </value>
```

Then I'd say they have value. So to answer your question: Comments are necessary when they say something that the code does not say.

An exception: it is good to have comments on anything that is *publicly* accessible if you're writing a library/API that will be available to the public. I *hate* using a library and seeing a function named `getAPCDGFSocket()` with no explanation of what an APCDGFSocket is (I'd be happy with something as simple as `This gets the Async Process Coordinator Data Generator File Socket`). So in that case, I'd say use some tool to generate all comments and then manually tweak the ones that need it (and please make sure your cryptic acronyms are explained).

Also, getters/setters are generally bad examples for "are comments necessary?" because they are usually quite obvious and comments aren't necessary. Comments are more important on functions that perform some algorithm where some explanation of *why* things are being done they way they are could make the code much more understandable and also make it easier for future programmers to work with.

...and finally, I'm pretty sure that this question is relevant for *all* styles of comments, not just those that are formatted using XML (which you are using because you're working in a .NET environment).

Comment: +1 - GhostDoc is a starting point for me to turn the first version, which is boilerplate, into the second version, which contains detailed domain knowledge.

Comment: +1 for the *why* part.  The DRY principle applies - do not repeat yourself, and if the code already does a pretty good job of describing the *what* part, your comments should focus on explaining something else (typically the *why*).

Comment: @DanielB or maybe you don't need comments at all ;) I agree for the most part with this answer except the word necessary in "Comments are necessary when they say something that the code does not say." I think if the code says everything needed then you don't need more information in comments even if the comments give information not in code.

Comment: @DanielB - XML Comments in .NET are primarily intended for situations where the end user programmer of a library or service doesn't have the source code available to them.

Comment: @jfrankcarr Should they be in the source code then? To me, that's what a separate document is for.

Comment: @Lattyware - XML comments integrate seamlessly with Visual Studio's Intellisense, a big time saver as compared to looking up stuff in a separate document.

Comment: @jfrankcarr Fair enough, then I'll just say what I said in my comment on the question - XML isn't suited to this task, it's massively too verbose. Incredibly poor choice for a standard in my opinion.

Comment: @jfrankcarr True, and to complicate matters further, XML comments are often used to generate separate, offline documentation as well.  Having said that, I find that comments that re-state the variable name (except with spaces this time) and the same for the method name are worse than nothing; they are simply noise to hide the occasional useful comment.  You also now have (at least) two things to keep updated, and outdated comments are even worse, they are downright dangerous.  Of course fxcop doesn't pick *those* up.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa I actually completely agree with you.  I think that if you thought things out and named things well, there should be no ambiguities, and everything should be *obvious*.  If it isn't, then comments are great to clarify.

Comment: <summary> - brief idea, 
<remarks> - Explanation of the internals that saves reader time analyzing

Answer (score 5):

The comments that look useless to users who can read the code become rather useful to users who have no access to the source. This happens when the class is used as an external API by people outside your organization: the HTMLs generated from your XML docs is their only way to learn about your classes.

That said, a comment that reiterates the method name with added spaces between the words remains useless. If your class is going to be used outside of your organization, you need to document at lest the valid ranges for your values. For example, you should say that setting `UnitOfMeasure` to `null` is illegal, that the value supplied to the setter must not contain spaces at the beginning or at the end of the string, and so on. You should also document the range of `LabelSerialNumber` if it differs from that of a plain `Int32`: perhaps it does not allow negative numbers<sup>*</sup>, or does not allow more than seven digits. Your internal users may take it for granted, because they look at serial numbers day in and day out, but the external users may be genuinely surprised to see an exception from what looks like an innocent setter.

---

<sup>*</sup> ...in which case `uint` may be a better choice

Comment: It's not just for when you don't have the source.  If your editor can parse them (like Visual Studio does with Xml Comments), they can give information as mouseover/popups without requiring you to navigate to a different file.  A 1 line range validator that limits an int to a narrower range is obvious when you go to the file where the setter is implemented; but having "FrobableID must be be between 0 and 1000" appear when you start typing "myFrobable.Fro..." and the autocomplete kicks in us a helpful reminder.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right about avoiding such useless comments. They make reading the code more difficult instead of making it easier, and are taking too much space.

In my practice people who write comments with getters/setters, tend to omit comments when those are really necessary (like building a 20-line sql-query for a component with no documentation).

I write comments when there are some other obvious solutions _ I indicate why exactly this approach has been used. Or when its hard to get the idea without knowing all of the details _ I briefly list the details that are necessary to understand the code.

The example you bring is more of writing comments to say that one writes comments rather than making others' (and theirs also) life easier.

BTW you can improve your ability of writing comments by returning to your old code and trying to comprehend it (you might even not recognize your own code in 2-3 months _ its absolutely like reading someone else's code). If you do this painlessly, than everything's just fine.

Comment: I don't know anyone who goes to effort to write comments on getters/setters anymore. If you're using almost any modern IDE (and even advanced text editors can support this via plugins), getters and setters can usually be documented very easily with a mouse-click or two, or the right keystroke (if it's been configured). Sometimes they're generated automatically when you generate code based on a database schema or WSDL...

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner, the person I was talking about was to leave the company, and I believe all those comments on getters/setters were done by that person to show that he/she did some effort to leave some documentation

Comment: Were all the bogo comments entered after the person gave notice?  I've seen people create empty/useless xml comments all over the place as a boneheaded way to stop VS from generating "Missing xml comment on publicly visible Foo" warnings.

Comment: @Dan Neely, I guess that person didn't really care and just added comments to say that comments are added. We usually don't pay much attention to comments, but if someone is to leave and is working on a component, it is a must to write clear readable code.